# Can you get Blazor WebAssembly to update a component using navigation?

Tags: routes, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have been using the Blazor WebAssembly example as my basis for a new application and its going pretty well. But I am hoping to make the NavMenu more dynamic.

In this case, I want to have admin / moderator specific options in the NavMenu, which I am trying to add after the user has logged in. I am currently using NavigationManager.NavigateTo(page, false) to switch between Razor pages. Its actually one Razor page mainly, so the login and a dynamic table is on the same page, depending on whether the app has a token or not.

I use the false option to ensure that it wont refresh the whole page, or the token will be lost. What I now find strange though, is that if I click the NavBar it will update the NavBar, showing the new admin options, which is nice. But I had hoped doing this same thing in the code with NavigationManager.NavigateTo(page, false) would also make the navbar update.

I have been looking at some videos and tutorials about Blazor and how to use components, but I still find it confusing how to call between components and get external / parent components to update.

I can think of different ways I probably could get it to work but I am hoping to figure out what the proper way to do it would be and follow code conventions. I suspect I am missing some basic way to do stuff like this even though I have been looking into this.

Code I have added

```
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counter">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Noter
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        @if (ApiService.Token.HasValue)
        {
            <li class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="logout">
                    <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> AdminStuff
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        }
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="logout">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Log ud
            </NavLink>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`AuthorizeView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component) with a role-based or policy authorization

Comment: This does seem like a great option for authorization, but I want to ensure that the admin / moderation page links are completely hidden unless authorized. Otherwise, I could make it work with my current system. Clicking the links on the NavBar already also does update it. I found a method called StateHasChanged() that all the pages have, so I think I will try to make a solution where I manually call this method on the NavBar after the user is logged in.

Comment: You can use the AuthorizeView in your nav-bar, or every where you want, I use it to render input or text depending on the user authorization, check this https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/blob/f629c85524a1f815b90f4da149c61533a01522af/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp/Shared/NavMenu.razor

Comment: or this https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/blob/master/src/Aguacongas.TheIdServer.BlazorApp/Components/Form/AuthorizeCheckbox.razor

Comment: Yes, and that does seem useful. But does it help update the NavBar when the authorization state changes?

Comment: Yes, that act as if (user.IsAuthorized) { display authorized links } else { display unauthorized links }

Comment: Good to know :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing this, but I suspect its not the best or most proper way of doing it.

I created a static EventManager like this:

```
    public static class EventManager
    {
        public static List<Action> renderActions = new List<Action>();
        public static void AddRenderAction(Action renderAction)
        {
            renderActions.Add(renderAction);
        }

        public static void TriggerRenderActions()
        {
            renderActions.ForEach(a => a.Invoke());
        }
    }
```

and then in the OnInitialized method of the NavMenu.razor component I add the "StateHasChanged" method which is inherented :

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            EventManager.AddRenderAction(()=>StateHasChanged());
        }
```

this way I can call EventManager.TriggerRenderActions() from anywhere to make all the added actions run.